# How to use dash(-) or dot(.) after footnote numbers in para feature with “manyfoot” package?

Tags: superscripts, manyfoot

I want to show footnotes like the below instead of making them superscript:

> 1-
>
> Or
>
> 1.

How should I do that?

```
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[roman]
```

[image: The desired footnotes are like this]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please provide a `MWE` for helping you in a better way...

Comment: Thank you Azetina for editing my post. I didn't know how to add some LaTex code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not providing any `MWE`, I have suggested based on the standard template and the tags are given below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{manyfoot}
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\normalfont\@textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
\let\@textsuperscript\relax    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark.}\ #1}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

This is for test\footnote{Footnote 1}.

This is for test\footnote{Footnote 2}.

\end{document}
```

Please let me know, if this does not meet your requirement...

Comment: Thank you. but most of my problem is about using \usepackage{manyfoot} with [para] feature: \usepackage[para]{manyfoot} In paragraph mode, the footnotes can not be shown with this macro code. any other suggestion?

Comment: How can I make MWE, what is that? Latex code you mean?

Comment: @Fatimasa an MWE is a Minimal Working Example. It means a small example document that, when it is compiled, shows your error or issue, or provides a starting point for adding a feature that you ask about. The post of MadyYuvi contains such an MWE. You can use his code as a starting point to make your own, for example changing `\usepackage{manyfoot}` into `\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}`, removing his `\def` line and the things below it until `\makeatother`, and adding things relevant to your issue. Then copy it into your post using the `edit` button at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much Marjin. I didn't know how to add this part to my question. I will try. Thanks again.

Comment: @Fatimasa Sorry, not able to understand your requirement, can you provide a screenshot for your requirement...

Comment: @MadyYuvi For sure! added one pic which shows my desired footnotes.